# Is Bootstrap 3.0 not working with Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just installed Centos 7.0 which comes with Apache 2.4. My bootstrap applications are not rendering properly. To be specific, the bootstrap components are not rendering correctly. For example, on  button with class=btn-primary, where the color is blue and the text is white, the text gets rendered black with Apache 2.4. There are many other issues.

My question is has anyone else had this problem? Is there a work-around such as a backwards-compatibility flag for html tags? I Googled and could not find any other references.

Thanks for sharing any findings you may have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We had the same problem. It took us 5-6hrs to debug. It was an alias mapping bootstrap.css in the welcome.conf in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ directory

```
Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
Alias /css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
Alias /css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
```

Just remove/comment out all the /css/ lines or disable to the welcome.conf. I don't know whether this comes with just CentOS or httpd package. It was a stupid thing to do.

Same thing happened to us with /error/ alias as well.

Comment: THANKS! It is weird that my non-minified version of the css worked, but now I see why. This is even better.

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem. The bootstrap.min.css file is not compatible with APache 2.4. I have no idea why but when I switched to the non-minified version, everything worked properly.

Comment: Bootstrap has nothing todo with Apache. It was not the problem... It's a resource file, it works on any web server. But the problem can be related to your server's cache.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. It is a brand-new server that's why I was confused. Perhaps the file was corrupted on transfer.